# Перенос текста c фоном

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой элемент, который нужно сверстать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всегда верстал такие штуки, просто помещая каждую строку в отдельный тэг с `display:inline-block`, но сейчас возникла необходимость сделать это без разделения строки на элементы.

Пробовал всему тексту прописывать `display:inline`, и все было бы хорошо, если бы высота строки не была больше размера текста (в данном случае у нас `font-size:19px` и `line-height:29px`). Ну и отступ между строками в 1 пиксель...

Подскажите, есть ли другой способ сверстать данный элемент без разделения на отдельные строки?

Comment: Добавьте свой код в вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данный способ подходит для большинства браузеров, но, вот в Firefox не все гладко отображается:

```css
div {
  max-width: 200px;
}

span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: -6px 0 0 black;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 29px;
  padding: 3px 6px 3px 0;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Длинный текст с переносом невмещающихся строк</span></div>
```

Второй же вариант придет по вкусу многим, кто любит современные браузеры:

```css
div {
  max-width: 200px;
}

span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 29px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Длинный текст с переносом невмещающихся строк</span></div>
```

Вот [поддержка](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxdecorationbreak) по второму способу. Я бы использовал именно его, так как при отсутствии поддержки, исчезнут лишь отступы боковые у фона и все будет выглядеть одинаково, в отличии от первого способа. Иных вариантов без JS сделать фон у текста с отступом нет.

Comment: Да, именно 19 и 29

Comment: @Cheg если не так, то напишите подробнее и пример кода.

Comment: @Cheg , этот вариант, но с `padding: 4px 10px 3px 0;` - это то, что вам нужно?

Comment: Да, практически то, что нужно. Спасибо!